# Print Option for Forms using Flows

Tags: visual-flows, flowscreen

Is there any option available in salesforce flows to print the End customer UI?
For example, I have developed a Form (like FirstName, LastName etc.) using flows. I need to provide an option to print it for the end user in desktop and mobile screens.
**Looking for solution within flows**
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a LWC component and write a code for print in that component based on your requirement.

Comment: Looking for solution within flows only. Any sugesstions on it?

Comment: You can use LWC component in flow.